# Cycle Notation for a Permutation Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

[image]

Can anyone thoroughly explain how you would arrive at this answer? I'm very confused with how you would do this problem.

Comment: please use Latex and don't post pictures

Comment: The photo is in Latex. It's legible and perfectly sufficient.

Comment: I'll also add that there was no need to close this question. The question was perfectly clear and was answered already by another individual. Seems like there is a lot of malicious game-playing on this site at times.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13677/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-pic-question

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11696/should-i-edit-a-question-everytime-i-see-an-image-in-it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do $\sigma_2$ for example. Since $\sigma_2(a)=2a \bmod{7}$, it maps $1\bmod{7}$ to $2 \bmod{7}$, $2 \bmod{7}$ to $4\bmod{7}$, and $4\bmod{7}$ to $8\bmod{7}$, which is $1 \bmod{7}$. Hence we have our first cycle $(1 2 4)$. $3$ is the next number not used, so we start with that. Then $\sigma_2$ maps $3 \bmod{7}$ to $6 \bmod{7}$ and $6 \bmod{7}$ to $12 \bmod{7}$. But $12 \bmod{7}$ is $5 \bmod{7}$, and that finally gets mapped to $10 \bmod{7}$, which is $3 \bmod{7}$ again. Hence we get $(3 6 5)$.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes a lot more sense!